# Easy way to implement dynamic views?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, set

View are useful constructions of [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). For those who never noticed (like me): for a dictionary `d` you can write `k = d.keys()` and even if you update `d` the variable `k` will still be giving you the updated keys. You can write then `k1 & k2` and it will always give you `d1.keys() & d2.keys()`

I want to implement this for my personal todo manager, but I would like to make complex views *dynamic*, or *lazily evaluated*. That is, I have some views called `so`, `post` and `priority` and I want to be able to write:

```
    now = so | phone & priority
```

so that later, when the `__repr__(now)` is called, evaluation is performed only at *that* point.

My first thought was to overload the logical operators so I changed `View.__and__` to create a new view that remembers itself being a composite of two subviews and applies `&` to them at computation. But there seem to be quite a lot of logical operators, so I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing.

Is there a standard library class that would help me with that? How can I simplify the process?

Comment: "My first thought was to overload the logical operators so I changed View.__and__ to create a new view that remembers itself being a composite of two subviews and applies & to them at computation."  That seems correct.  I don't know if there are any libraries that can ease the repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a collection.UserList class which defines up most of them, perhaps that would mean you don't have to override all of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "easy" way to do so, *especially* if you want the lazy behaviour as stated. But still, there aren't that many logical operators, only three of them: `__and__`, `__or__` and `__xor__`.

(for additional efficiency you can optionally implement the in-place versions `__iand__`, `__ior__` and `__ixor__`, but if you don't the normal versions will be invoked as a fallback)